# Airplay to Apple TV with Bluetooth speakers doesn't work

Tags: bluetooth, appletv, airplay, mirroring

My Apple TV uses Bluetooth speakers that play normal Apple TV sounds. When I use an app to send AirPlay to the tv, there is no sound.

However if I use mirroring sound to the Apple TV via bluetooth speakers works fine.

Is this supported or is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Apple TV the only device connected to the Bluetooth speaker? If not you will likely run into issues, especially if the phone that you're going to be streaming over airplay is connected, it might try and double up and confuse the speaker so you should forget the speaker on all devices except for the Apple TV. Ensure that it's connected in: Settings > Remotes and Devices > Bluetooth. Also, have you made sure to set the output device as the bluetooth speaker in Settings > Video and Audio > Audio Output?

Comment: yes it's the only device and, as said, all settings look good as it works fine when mirroring (video and audio). Audio only streaming does not work.

Comment: what application are you trying to stream the audio from?

Comment: any audio app, like apple music but also amazon music, di.fm

Comment: and just to be sure, when you open the Apple Music app on your phone and play audio you then are pressing the airplay button in the apple music app and selecting your Apple TV as the output source? I'm just trying to recreate the scenario so want to make sure I'm creating the same environment

Comment: correct but also tried from the control center